# How to alter SQL Table default data type during design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to change the default data type when designing a table in SQL Server Management Studio Table Designer. My current default is nchar(10) and I am creating a table with a lot of integer data types. I looked in Tools Options but could not find anyplace to change this. I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, but requires a modification of the registry.
This is a tiresome change to make every time you wish to change the default, so I agree with NYCdotNet.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\DataProject
```

[image: Screenshot of regpath]

Comment: I'll give that a try, I don't think I need the default changed that often. In this particular table had 81 fields and most where decimal(9,4). Thanks.

Comment: This didn't exist for me - I have SQL Express 2012 though with SSMS 2012 Basic. I searched the whole registry for SSVDefaultColumnType to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're ready to create your table using T-SQL and not the designer.  A variation of the below code will cover you for putting together a basic schema and if you want to do more stuff you can always revise the table in the designer later.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableName (
  MyID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  MyColumn1 INT NOT NULL,
  MyColumn2 INT NULL,
  MyColumn3 VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MyID)
)
```

Comment: I see your point, if I had some intellisense I might agree hardily but I think that using the designer and being able to tab though the properties is faster. I realize now that where I saw the option to default the data type was in MS Access, not SSMC. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: My apologies, read your question too fast. This solution is for the visual designer in VS2015, not SQLSMS. I will leave the answer up anyway.**

This has been changed in Visual Studio 2015. It is now in:

> Options > Database Tools > Table and Database Designers > Column Options

[image]

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for, as I remembered seeing it... Just in the wrong software. Guess I'll head back into Visual Studio ...